# How to wait for Azure Search to finish indexing document? For integration testing purpose

Tags: .net, asynchronous, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

### Scenario

I'm building a suite of automated integration tests. Each test push data into the Azure Search index before querying it and verifying the expected results.

### Problem

The indexation happens asynchronously in the service and data aren't immediatly available after the indexing call returns successfully.
The test execute of course too rapidly most of the time.

### What I've tried

I've tried querying the document until it's found:

```cs
// Wait for the indexed document to become available
while (await _index.Documents.SearchAsync("DocumentId").Results.SingleOrDefault() == null) { }
```

But oddly enough, a search query just behind won't generally find anything:

```cs
// Works 10% of the time, even after the above loop
await _index.Documents.SearchAsync(query.Text);
```

Using an arbitrary pause works, but it's not guaranteed and I'd like the tests to execute as fast as possible.

```cs
Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

---

[Azure Search documentation:](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-import-data-dotnet/#iv-import-data-to-the-index)

> Finally, the code in the example above delays for two seconds. Indexing happens asynchronously in your Azure Search service, so the sample application needs to wait a short time to ensure that the documents are available for searching. **Delays like this are typically only necessary in demos, tests, and sample applications.**

Aren't there any solution without scarifying tests performance?

Answer (score 3):

If your service has multiple search units, **there is no way to determine when a document has been fully indexed**. This is a deliberate decision to favor increased indexing/query performance over strong consistency guarantees.

If you're running tests against a single unit search service, the approach (keep checking for document existence with a query rather than a lookup) should work.

Note that **on a *free* tier search service this will *not* work** as it's hosted on multiple shared resources and does not count as a single unit. You'll see the same brief inconsistency that you would with a dedicated multi-unit service

Otherwise, one possible improvement would be to use retries along with a smaller sleep time.

Comment: Additionally, consider changing your tests to have a common set of data that they depend upon that gets indexed in a [test class initialization section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute.aspx)

Comment: I'm using the free pricing tier, where resources are shared. I suppose this count as a single unit?  
Is it possible that, just after indexing, a query by document key will find the document but not a more complex query using regular fields?

Comment: @Sean Saleh, Yes, I refactored the tests to populate the index once by test run.

Comment: @Clément, if it's a free service, it's hosted on multiple shared resources and does not count as a single unit. You'll see the same brief inconsistency that you would with a dedicated multi-unit service.

Comment: And while it is possible for the first query by document key to succeed and the second query by keyword to fail, it's not a function of the complexity of the query. It's because there is a brief window of inconsistency while the indexing operation completes across all replicas.

Answer (score 1):

[The other answer by @HeatherNakama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40117836/419956) was very helpful. I want to add to it, but first a paraphrased summary:

> **There is *no* way to reliably know a document is ready to be searched on *all* replicas**, so the only way a spin-lock waiting until a document is found could work is to use a single-replica search service. (**Note: the free tier search service is *not* single-replica**, and you can't do anything about that.)

With that in mind, I've created a [sample repository with Azure Search integration tests](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-azure-search-integration-tests) that roughly works like this:

```
private readonly ISearchIndexClient _searchIndexClient;

private void WaitForIndexing(string id)
{
    // For the free tier, or a service with multiple replicas, resort to this:
    // Thread.Sleep(2000);

    var wait = 25;

    while (wait <= 2000)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(wait);
        var result = fixture.SearchService.FilterForId(id);
        if (result.Result.Results.Count == 1) return;
        if (result.Result.Results.Count > 1) throw new Exception("Unexpected results");
        wait *= 2;
    }

    throw new Exception("Found nothing after waiting a while");
}

public async Task<DocumentSearchResult<PersonDto>> FilterForId(string id)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) || !Guid.TryParse(id, out var _))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Can only filter for guid-like strings", nameof(id));
    }

    var parameters = new SearchParameters
    {
        Top = 2, // We expect only one, but return max 2 so we can double check for errors
        Skip = 0,
        Facets = new string[] { },
        HighlightFields = new string[] { },
        Filter = $"id eq '{id}'",
        OrderBy = new[] { "search.score() desc", "registeredAtUtc desc" },
    };

    var result = await _searchIndexClient.Documents.SearchAsync<PersonDto>("*", parameters);

    if (result.Results.Count > 1)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Search filtering for id '{id}' unexpectedly returned more than 1 result. Are you sure you searched for an ID, and that it is unique?");
    }

    return result;
}
```

This might be used like this:

```
[SerializePropertyNamesAsCamelCase]
public class PersonDto
{
    [Key] [IsFilterable] [IsSearchable]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    [IsSortable] [IsSearchable]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [IsSortable]
    public DateTimeOffset? RegisteredAtUtc { get; set; }
}
```

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(0)]
[InlineData(1)]
[InlineData(2)]
[InlineData(3)]
[InlineData(5)]
[InlineData(10)]
public async Task Can_index_and_then_find_person_many_times_in_a_row(int count)
{
    await fixture.SearchService.RecreateIndex();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
        var dto = new PersonDto { Email = $"{guid}@example.org" };
        await fixture.SearchService.IndexAsync(dto);

        WaitForIndexing(dto);

        var searchResult = await fixture.SearchService.Search(dto.Id);

        Assert.Single(searchResult.Results, p => p.Document.Id == dto.Id);
    }
}
```

I have tested and confirmed that this reliably stays *green* on a Basic tier search service with 1 replica, and intermittently becomes *red* on the free tier.

Answer (score 0):

Use a FluentWaitDriver or similar component to wait in tests, if waiting is needed only for tests. I wouldn't pollute the app with thread delays. Azure indexer will have a few acceptable milliseconds-seconds delay, provided the nature of your search instance.