# How to reliably know if a document is searchable in Azure Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I'm trying to write code that checks if a document that I just uploaded to Azure Search has been fully indexed and is ready to be found through searches. I'm having trouble finding a way to do this.

Here's some things I've tried, using the `ISearchIndexClient` from the NuGet SDK:

- I've tried doing a `search=* & filter=id eq {myguid}` search, but that would give false positives (return results, when searching for fields other than `id` would *not* yet return the document)
- I've tried doing `search={myguid}` but then the fuzzyness of the search would yield multiple documents
- I've tried using `Documents.Get<T>(key)` on the document, but that will give false positives (as kindof expected)
- I've tried using `Documents.Count()` on the index to see that an extra document was added, but that also gives false positives (the count is increased *before* a document is searchable)

Is there any reliable way in Azure Search using either the SDK or alternatively with the API directly to know that a document has been fully indexed and is searchable?

Comment: This has been addressed and answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108369/how-to-wait-for-azure-search-to-finish-indexing-document-for-integration-testin).

Comment: @EdneyHolder Ah, yes, you are right, I've asked a duplicate question. I will try to place a bounty on that question instead to see if I can get a real answer there.